# What is difference between Celery Beats, Celery worker, Threads and Multiprocessors?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

What is the difference between:-
Celery beats and Celery Worker, and if Celery worker works just like threads or multiprocessors, why do we use celery worker especially?
Thank you.

I tried working with threads and Celery worker but found that threads is more clear and simple.

Comment: Because you can stop the server at any time, so the tasks that are running, then are gone... So it makes the tasks persistent.

Comment: Threads also are harder to control in the number of tasks that run concurrently. This means that one can just submit a huge number of tasks to render the server unresponsive.